# Unable to instantiate a class using classloader

Tags: java, reflection

i load a class using ClassLoader but i am not able to create an object of that class.Here is the code.What is the problem?Help

```
Cloader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new File(binfolderurl).toURI().toURL()},ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader);

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Cloader);

Class clss = Cloader.loadClass("Someclass");

Object myobj =  clss.newInstance();
```

Comment: Does the class have default constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting an Exception, describing what did not work. Did you?

The most likely reason is the class not having a default (no-arg) constructor, or that constructor being not public.

Comment: i didnt get any exception.i have defined default constructor

Comment: And the class needs to be public.

Comment: after instantiation i use the object to invoke a method which is not happenening

Comment: if you get an object, then the newInstance() worked. What do you mean by "invoking a method is not happening"?

Comment: am not getting the object itself